# Is there a Legal/Standard/Pereferred JSON Format?

Tags: json

Is there such a thing that would make one JSON data preferable to another?
For example given these two formats:

1.

```
{ 
  "status":"ok",
  "result":
  {
    "0":{"id":"1", "name":"English"},
    "1":{"id":"2", "name":"Chinese"},
    "2":{"id":"3", "name":"Portuguese"},
  }
}
```

And
2.

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "result": [
             {"id": 1,"name": "English"}, 
             {"id": 2,"name": "Chinese"}, 
             {"id": 3,"name": "Portuguese"}
            ]
}
```

Which one is a more standard JSON? or are there different numbers of accepted standard JSON formats?

Comment: well I would say it is like the argument [XML Elements vs Tags](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/dtd_el_vs_attr.asp) , the answers lies in more of  your design choice than any specification.

Comment: I would personally use the second one. The first one is harder to iterate over and there's no clear reason to use objects to do the job of an array.

Comment: @Blender : 2nd choice is also my choice, but the other developer is asking for the 1st one!

Comment: @Arjang: Ask him why the first one is better than the second one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is agnostic to whitespace not contained in strings and will ignore it.  There is no universal standard for formatting, although individual organizations will probably choose to format static JSON in a way that is more readable.  JSON is intended to be consumed programatically moreso than by people, so most stringifiers will probably create the JSON without whitespace at all.

There is a slight difference in the two examples above: the first one has strings as the values of the `"id"` keys while the second has numbers.  Both are valid JSON strings though.

EDIT: I also want to add that there is a significant difference between using an object with numeric keys `{"0": 1, "1": 2}` and an array `[1, 2]` in that arrays represent *ordinal* data.